# Why does Sparsearray diagonalization by Krylov technique become slower for very large sizes?

Tags: performance-tuning, eigenvalues, sparse-arrays

Here is an example sparse matrix, taken from [example Hamiltonian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240938/efficiently-populate-a-sparsearray-for-a-set-of-rules-for-a-constrained-basis/240951?noredirect=1#comment620935_240951), which was a question I asked before in this forum.

```
N1 = 28;
X1 = Range[0, 2^N1 - 1];
X1 = Pick[X1, BitAnd[X1, BitShiftLeft[X1, 1]], 0];
X1 = Pick[X1, BitGet[X1, 0] BitGet[X1, N1 - 1], 0];
len = Length[X1];


i = Range[0, len N1 - 1];
s2 = Quotient[i, len];
s1 = Subtract[i, len s2] + 1;
labels = X1 + 1;
keys = BitXor[X1[[s1]], Power[2, s2]] + 1;
lookuptable = Normal[SparseArray[ Partition[labels, 1] -> Range[len], {2^N1 - 1}]];
k1 = lookuptable[[keys]];
pos = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Unitize[k1], 1];

Q1 = SparseArray[Transpose[{s1[[pos]], k1[[pos]]}] -> \[Tau]];
\[Tau]=-0.5;
```

Now when I try to get the largest eigenvalue for this system using,

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "ParallelOptions" -> {"MKLThreadNumber" -> 8, 
    "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 8}];
Ei = -Eigenvalues[Q1, 1];
```

For N1=28, while executing the diagonalization, all 8 threads are fully used(picture attached). For N1=30 however they are not (picture attached). While initially I thought this might be due to the RAM constraints of my machine, it is not because machines with 10x my RAM has the same problem. Is there some internal limitation? Note how my system has 8 threads available.[image: N1=30]
[image: N1=28]

Comment: My guess is that the question is how many real (physical) cores does your machine have.  I'd say, that's the maximum number of threads you can expect to see working.

Comment: Yes, but why does the system not use maximum cores in N=30 while it does for N=28?

Comment: My guess is that above N>28 the system is too large for the hyperthreading stuff and the cores can only offer what they really have available in terms of compute power. Hyperthreading works when the applications running in a core are different enough that different components of the core are utilized. That's really the case for numerical computation.